Auto-populating foreign keys in child table with two parent tables in QGIS form of child table
I’m working with a parent-child relationship in QGIS, where I have two parent tables (ANZ and PI) and one child table (GEOM). The GEOM table contains foreign keys "anz_id" and "pi_id" that reference ANZ and PI, respectively.
Here’s the workflow I’m trying to achieve:
I have a form for GEOM where I can see and add related records for both parent tables. When I create a new record in GEOM, the foreign key fields ("anz_id" and "pi_id") should initially be empty, allowing me to later add the related ANZ or PI record.
If I add a record in the ANZ (or PI) table through the related field in the GEOM form, I’d like the new ID generated in ANZ (or PI) to automatically populate into the corresponding foreign key field ("anz_id" and "pi_id") in GEOM.
I’ve been able to make this work when adding records from the ANZ form, where a new GEOM child record gets the ANZ ID correctly. However, since GEOM has two parent tables, I’m unable to configure it to update both "anz_id" and "pi_id" automatically based on which parent form I’m using. Configuring this directly in the database is not an option for me.
Has anyone set up a similar structure with two parent tables and one child table in QGIS? Any advice on how to dynamically populate the correct foreign key in GEOM when creating records from either parent form?

Are you tables saved locally or are they stored in a database? And which tables do have a geometry?

My tables are in PostGres db. GEOM table has geometry.

Polymorphic relations seem close to what you need : https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/joins_relations.html#polymorphic-relations

And how are features of the child table linked to the parent tables?

There is fk fields in child table GEOM (anz_id, pi_id). In parent tables are fields id.

These id of ANZ and PI are generated by PostrGres, so when I add new record, QGIS get value of id for the new record.
